# How do I merge two separate commits so that a file is completely removed in IntelliJ/Git?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

In my project, I had one file which is over 100 MB (which means I am unable to upload it to Github). I committed my changes, including the addition of the file. I then realized that the file was unneeded, and I removed it. However, when I committed again, I was still unable to push my commits because of that one file which was removed being over the 100 MB limit, even though I removed it in the subsequent commit. Is there a way to merge these two commits so that the file never existed so that it doesn't try to push it to Github?

I know I can use something like git-lfs, but I was just curious to see if there was a faster way to fix this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git rebase -i` starting from a commit which *doesn't* have the 100MB file, and edit the commits that wrongly add this file in your history.